How can I install Python packages system-wide on MacOS?
For example, if I run:
pip3 install matplotlib

I get error:
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
    xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a Python library that isn't in Homebrew,
    use a virtual environment:
    
    python3 -m venv path/to/venv
    source path/to/venv/bin/activate
    python3 -m pip install xyz
    
    If you wish to install a Python application that isn't in Homebrew,
    it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. You can install pipx with
    
    brew install pipx
    
    You may restore the old behavior of pip by passing
    the '--break-system-packages' flag to pip, or by adding
    'break-system-packages = true' to your pip.conf file. The latter
    will permanently disable this error.
    
    If you disable this error, we STRONGLY recommend that you additionally
    pass the '--user' flag to pip, or set 'user = true' in your pip.conf
    file. Failure to do this can result in a broken Homebrew installation.
    
    Read more about this behavior here: <https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/>

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.0 -> 24.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python3.12 -m pip install --upgrade pip

And when I do:
brew install matplotlib

That just hangs for ever, even hours later, even though installing matplotlib in a venv only takes a few minutes.
What gives? How can I install matplotlib system-wide using pip3 on MacOS, and bypass the stupid externally managed error?

Did you check this thread --> externally-managed-network

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+externally-managed-environment

Try following the advice in the message. First,
python3 -m pip install matplotlib --break-system-packages

If you are doing this all the time, it would also make sense to edit your pip.conf file. The file is usually located at  ~/.config/pip/ for macOS, though you may need to create it if it does not already exist. Add the following lines to your pip.conf file:
[global]
break-system-packages = true
user = true

Finally, upgrade pip:
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip --break-system-packages

This will bypass the PEP 668 protections and allow the installation of packages globally without creating virtual environments.

Upgrading Pip will absolutely not "bypass the PEP 668 protections". If you mean in conjunction with the pip.conf edit, Pip has recognized the pip.conf file for a very long time, and if Pip weren't recognizing the --break-system-packages option then the command shown for self-update wouldn't work, either. Keeping Pip up to date is a good idea in general, but not relevant to the problem. Aside from that, creating virtual environments is generally the correct approach. Adding code to the system environment (even with --user) can have unintended consequences.
